# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present

Tags: wordpress, search, fetch

I have a multi-vendor store where every vendor has his own dashboard. There is a product tab in dashboard to view their products and they can edit them. I added a search bar to update their list based on the keyword they are trying to find. Recently this search bar is stuck on "Please wait.." and doesn't update the list. I tried to disable some of the recent updates I made but nothing works. Also, I shows this error in Chrome inspect tool.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
> at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Here is the code of the products list

```
<?php global $products;
 global $edd_logs;
 global $post;

?>

<?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_status_bar(); ?>
    
    

    
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
    <h3 class="fes-headers" id="mayofes-orders-page-title"><?php echo EDD_FES()->helper->get_product_constant_name( $plural = true, $uppercase = true ) ?></h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
       <div class="fes-cs-search_bar">
    <form action="/" method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Products..." id="keyword" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch()">
        
    </form>
    
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search_result" id="datafetch">
        <ul>
            <li>Please wait..</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<div class="fes--list--style-p" id="fes-product-list">


    
                <?php
                if ( count( $products ) > 0 ) {
                    foreach ( $products as $product ) : ?>
                        <div class="product--flex--fes">
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td fes--mob--image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->ID, array( 100, 100,true ) ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td fes--mob--title"><?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_title( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_status( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php  $download = $edd_logs->get_log_count($product->ID, 'file_download'); echo ( is_null( $download ) ? '0' : $download ); ?> <?php esc_html_e('Downloads','mayosis'); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_actions( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_date( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <?php do_action( 'fes-product-table-column-value', $product ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                } else {
                    echo '<div><div class = "fes-product-list-td" >' . sprintf( _x( 'No %s found', 'FES lowercase plural setting for download','mayosis' ), EDD_FES()->helper->get_product_constant_name( $plural = true, $uppercase = false ) ) . '</div></div>';
                }
                ?>
            

</div>
<?php EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_pagination();
```

And below is the function.php code related to the above code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
}

// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){
    $authorID = get_current_user_id();
       $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'download',  'author'=> $authorID ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
     
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); 
        global $products;
        global $edd_logs;
 global $post;
        
        ?>
       
 <div class="product--flex--fes">
     <div class = "fes-product-list-td fes--mob--image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $product->ID, array( 100, 100,true ) ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td fes--mob--title"><?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_title( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_status( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php  $download = $edd_logs->get_log_count($product->ID, 'file_download'); echo ( is_null( $download ) ? '0' : $download ); ?> <?php esc_html_e('Downloads','mayosis'); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_actions( $product->ID ); ?></div>
                            <div class = "fes-product-list-td"><?php echo EDD_FES()->dashboard->product_list_date( $product->ID ); ?></div>
     </div>
            

         <?php endwhile;
       
        wp_reset_postdata();  
        else :
            echo "No Product Found";
    endif;
                
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch() function is built in with the javascript so you should rename your function something else like fetchProducts()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetchProducts(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Products..." id="keyword" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetchProducts()">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. Actually I tried this yesterday but didn't work. But today I renamed to fetchProducts() and added the javascript code at the same page with the input field and I kept the fetch() function the same in functions.php and it worked fine. Thank you so much and I really appreciate your support. :)